Limited extracted data on AWS Textract?
I am working with the AWS Texctract api to extract the data from a pdf but textract only returns the first 4 pages, my pdf are not more than 8 pages long and do not exceed the 500mb limit, any idea?
Number of pages is detected
Cut on the 4th page
I need to know if there is something causing this or if it is just a problem with my code.

Use the AWS console - do you get the same result?
